# What does this error in Prolog mean?

Tags: prolog, logic, declarative

I'm making a little program in Prolog to find out the capitals of a country entered, bu I get this error all the time on line 10 and 11:

ERROR: c:/users/cesar downs/documents/capital.pl:10: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: c:/users/cesar downs/documents/capital.pl:11: Syntax error: Operator expected

I really don´t get it, heres the code:

```
capital_of(guatemala, guatemala).
capital_of(tegucigalpa, honduras).
capital_of(san_salvador, el_salvador).
capital_of(managua, nicaragua).
capital_of(san_jose, costa_rica).
capital_of(panamá, panamá).

%Rules

Capital:- write(‘Enter the country: ‘),Read(Country),Answer(Country).
Answer(Country):- capital_of(Country,City),Write(‘The capital of: ‘),Write(Country),Write(‘ is ‘),Write(City).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an aside, also consider using format/2. For example, instead of:

```
answer(Country) :-
    capital_of(Capital, Country),
    write('The capital of: '),
    write(Country),
    write(' is '),
    write(Capital).
```

you can write:

```
answer(Country) :-
    capital_of(Capital, Country),
    format("The capital of: ~w is ~w", [Country,Capital]).
```

Answer (score 2):

- Prolog doesn't seem to like the `á` character.
- You should use a single quote `'` not the `‘` character.
- It's `write` and `read`, not `Write` and `Read`.

Try this:

```
capital_of(guatemala, guatemala).
capital_of(tegucigalpa, honduras).
capital_of(san_salvador, el_salvador).
capital_of(managua, nicaragua).
capital_of(san_jose, costa_rica).
capital_of(panama, panama).

%Rules

capital :-
    write('Enter the country: '),
    read(Country),
    answer(Country).

answer(Country) :-
    capital_of(Country,City),
    write('The capital of: '),
    write(Country),
    write(' is '),
    write(City).
```

Test run:

```
| ?- consult('test.pl').
compiling /home/aioobe/tmp/prolog/test.pl for byte code...
/home/aioobe/tmp/prolog/test.pl compiled, 20 lines read

yes
| ?- capital.
Enter the country: managua.
The capital of: managua is nicaragua

yes
| ?-
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it means that you have an error on your tenth and eleventh line, in your file c:/users/cesar downs/documents/capital.pl and that for both those lines the error is that an operator is missing.

In fact in your case it's not so much the missing operator that is wrong but the fact that you name your predicates with a capital letter to start while it's reserved for variables in Prolog. That makes the interpreter go nuts!

A correct version would be:

```
capital_of(guatemala, guatemala).
capital_of(tegucigalpa, honduras).
capital_of(san_salvador, el_salvador).
capital_of(managua, nicaragua).
capital_of(san_jose, costa_rica).
capital_of('panamá', 'panamá').

%Rules

capital :-
    write('Enter the country: '),
    read(Country),
    answer(Country).

answer(Country) :-
    capital_of(Country, City),
    write('The capital of: '),
    write(Country),
    write(' is '),
    write(City).
```

EDIT: as pointed out there are other problems such as the use of proper single quotes to delimit atoms `'` and use of special characters, instead of replacing the `á` with an `a` you can just wrap your atom in single quotes as I did in my code though.

EDIT2: btw try to indent your code properly. Prolog code is very hard to read if you oneline all your predicates.